# Tweepy: Trying to detect a university filter or firewall

Tags: ssl, firewall, tweepy

I think my university recently changed a firewall or filtering protocol with regards to Twitter's streaming API.   However, for me to provide them more information, I'm going to have to figure out the details.

Ok, below is the simplest possible program to collect data from Twitter's stream:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


ckey="[OMITED]"
csecret="[OMITED]"
atoken="[OMITED]"
asecret="[OMITED]"

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return(True)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

When I run this program on my laptop/home desktop, it works fine.  However, I have a university computer setup for data collection and it produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 228, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 172, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 106, in _run
    conn.connect()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1278, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 352, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 579, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)
```

Now, the thing is, I can open up Safari and browse the web.  Further, data collection like this use to work (as of a month ago).  The error says the SSL cert is failing verification (but strangely the original OAuth seems to work -- it is the filter command kicking up the error).  Is there a way to get it to spit out if that is because an intermediate cert has been put in place?  Or maybe a port is being blocked?  Basically, is there a way to get a lot more details so I can go the university and say: 'you are blocking X'?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the situation.  It was an error relating to SSL sites that were signed with Digicerts.